# extraction of string using reg exp.using python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I tried to extract 'Startpoint' Match from my text file using python regular exp.

and this wasn't displaying me the desired result.
am a very beginner and was trying to extract all the matches of the string 'Startpoint' from my text file.someone pls help.

```python
import re 
with open('report.txt') as file: 
    f = file.readlines() 
    # pattern=(r'(Startpoint\:*\s[a-zA-Z]\w*)') 
    pattern=(r'([^S..t$]\:*\s[A-Z]\W*)') 
    print(pattern) 
    mat=re.match(r'([^S..t$]\:*\s[A-Z]\W*)',f,re.M|re.I) 
    print(mat)
```

Also, i have tried, this and since i have used re.sub its removing my my string 'S'

```python
with open('report.txt') as file:
    text=file.read()
    f=file.readlines()
    pat=re.sub(r'([^S..t$]:*\s[A-Z]\W*)'," ",text)#for replacing
    print(pat)
```

i have included some info. from my text here,

```
exintf_max.txt:3870:  Startpoint: EXINTF_DATA0

exintf_max.txt:3920:  Startpoint: EXINTF_DATA9

exintf_max.txt:3972:  Startpoint: EXINTF_DATA11

exintf_max.txt:4022:  Startpoint: top/soc/xintf_cntrl/lv_temp_xintf_rg_chip_1_select_enable_reg

exintf_max.txt:4054:  Startpoint: EXINTF_DATA15

exintf_max.txt:4105:  Startpoint: top/soc/xintf_cntrl/lv_temp_xintf_rg_chip_0_select_enable_reg

exintf_max.txt:4137:  Startpoint: EXINTF_DATA1

exintf_max.txt:4189:  Startpoint: EXINTF_DATA6

exintf_max.txt:4241:  Startpoint: EXINTF_DATA10

exintf_max.txt:4290:  Startpoint: EXINTF_DATA10

exintf_max.txt:4341:  Startpoint: top/soc/xintf_cntrl/lv_temp_xintf_rg_XWR_reg
```

this above information i could get through grep command, i want to get the same using python script.

pls help me. am a very beginner.

Comment: Could you [edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109) your question and also give us an example of the text that you want to extract information?

Answer (score 1):

Just to check a line of that text..., then you can use it inside a loop.

```python
import re
# txt = "exintf_max.txt:4341: Startpoint: top/soc/xintf_cntrl/lv_temp_xintf_rg_XWR_reg"
txt = "exintf_max.txt:4290: Startpoint: EXINTF_DATA10"
m = re.match("[\w_]+.\w+:(\d+):\s?(Startpoint):\s?(.*)",txt)
if m:
  print(m.groups())
  print(m.group(3))
```

Comment: i couldn't understand. could you please explain me still more clearer

Answer (score 1):

To get the values in Python for the string Startpoint, you could use:

```
^[^:\n]*:\d+:\s*Startpoint:\s*(.+)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[^:\n]*` Optionally match any character except `:` or a newline
- `:\d+:`  Match 1+ digits between colons
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `Startpoint:` Match literally
- `\s*(.+)` Match optional whitspace chars

If you want to match spaces without newlines, you can change `\s` to `[^\S\n]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HqHaZp/1)

Example code

```
import re

with open('report.txt') as file:
    f = file.read()
    pattern = r"^[^:\n]*:\d+:\s*Startpoint:\s*(.+)"
    print(re.findall(pattern, f, re.M))
```

Output

```
[
'EXINTF_DATA0',
'EXINTF_DATA9',
'EXINTF_DATA11',
'top/soc/xintf_cntrl/lv_temp_xintf_rg_chip_1_select_enable_reg', 
'EXINTF_DATA15', 
'top/soc/xintf_cntrl/lv_temp_xintf_rg_chip_0_select_enable_reg',
'EXINTF_DATA1',
'EXINTF_DATA6',
'EXINTF_DATA10',
'EXINTF_DATA10', 
'top/soc/xintf_cntrl/lv_temp_xintf_rg_XWR_reg'
]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to grab what comes after `Startpoint:` you can just do:

```
import re
from pathlib import Path

path = Path("report.txt")

pat = re.compile(r'.*Startpoint:\s*(\S*)')
pat.findall(path.read_text())
```

This basically goes past any match before `Startpoint:` then gets whatever comes after it that isn't a space.

This outputs:

```
['EXINTF_DATA0', 'EXINTF_DATA9', 'EXINTF_DATA11',
 'top/soc/xintf_cntrl/lv_temp_xintf_rg_chip_1_select_enable_reg', 'EXINTF_DATA15',
'top/soc/xintf_cntrl/lv_temp_xintf_rg_chip_0_select_enable_reg', 
'EXINTF_DATA1', 'EXINTF_DATA6', 'EXINTF_DATA10', 'EXINTF_DATA10', 
'top/soc/xintf_cntrl/lv_temp_xintf_rg_XWR_reg']
```

Comment: i just wanna to grab all the 'Startpoint:' first

Comment: also everything is getting printed as list; i tried adding end=' ' @ the print statement, still then its getting printed as list. tried the same code as,                                                                       path = Path("report.txt")

pat = re.compile(r'.*Startpoint:\s*(\S*)')
s=pat.findall(path.read_text())
print(s,end=' ')                                                      Is there anything else i could do so to get in vertical manner without grtting printed as list?

Comment: You need to give the expected output. What are you trying to do?

Comment: pat.findall(path.read_text())
here, read_text() is similar to 'file.readlines()' ?

Comment: @SwarnaLSwarnaLakshmiNarasim No, `read_text()` returns all the content of the file as a single string while `readlines()` return of list of strings, where each string is a line of the file;

Comment: Input-file name : report.txt
  Startpoint: EXINTF_DATA12

  Startpoint: EXINTF_DATA12

  Startpoint: EXINTF_DATA5

  Startpoint: EXINTF_DATA11

  Startpoint: EXINTF_DATA5

  Startpoint: EXINTF_DATA4

  Startpoint: EXINTF_DATA11

  Startpoint: EXINTF_DATA15

  Startpoint: EXINTF_DATA9
 i got this o/p and also this was my expected o/p.

Comment: also this was my script, which gave me the above desired o/p,                                                                                          #working & getting o/p as 'Startpoint: EXINTF_DATA*'
import re
file = open(input("Input-file name : ") , "r")
fi = file.readlines()
for line in fi:
    if re.match(r'^[^\n(E|P):]*:\s[EXINTF_DATA\d]*\d',line):
        print(line)